# How to call an exact method from web service using ASP/VBScript

Tags: web-services, vbscript, xmlhttprequest

I want to send data to the method `SalePaymentRequest` from this web service, but I don't know where to put the name of `SalePaymentRequest` method:

https://pec.shaparak.ir/NewIPGServices/Sale/SaleService.asmx

Here is my code in Classic ASP/VBScript:

```
amount = 1000
id = 1
pin = "mypincode"
posturl = "https://pec.shaparak.ir/NewIPGServices/Sale/SaleService.asmx"
backurl = "mywebsite/back.asp"

DataToSend = "LoginAccount=" & pin & "&Amount=" & amount & "&OrderId="& id & "&CallBackUrl="&backurl

Dim xmlhttp 
Set xmlhttp = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.Open "POST", posturl, False
xmlhttp.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
xmlhttp.Send DataToSend
Response.Write xmlhttp.ResponseText
Set xmlhttp = Nothing
```

Comment: The page you referenced even points you towards the [documentation](https://pec.shaparak.ir/NewIPGServices/Sale/SaleService.asmx?op=SalePaymentRequest). You need to send a [SOAP request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22945505/1630171) to the server. What is not clear about that?

Comment: Should I send data in place of <requestData /> in documentation? Would you please rewrite my data in soap request format as an answer?

Comment: Well a SOAP request can be obtained from the developers. They have tools and resources to generate it. I suggest you talk to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By refering to the [documentation](https://pec.shaparak.ir/NewIPGServices/Sale/SaleService.asmx?op=SalePaymentRequest) of web service I found that the post should be a SOAP request and for accessing the `SalePaymentRequest` method, there is a SOPAction url introduced by service itself. I had to post SOAP to that URL. The format of SOAP document is totally defined by service documentation:

```
pin = "mypincode"
posturl = "https://pec.shaparak.ir/NewIPGServices/Sale/SaleService.asmx"
backurl = "mywebsite/back.asp"
'///This is the exact answer to my question! This URL defines the method target:
SOAPAction ="https://pec.Shaparak.ir/NewIPGServices/Sale/SaleService/SalePaymentRequest"

soap="<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>"
soap=soap& "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">"
soap=soap& "<soap:Body>"
soap=soap& "<SalePaymentRequest xmlns=""https://pec.Shaparak.ir/NewIPGServices/Sale/SaleService"">"
soap=soap& "<requestData>"
soap=soap& "<LoginAccount>" & pin & "</LoginAccount>"
soap=soap& "<Amount>" & amount &"</Amount>"
soap=soap& "<OrderId>"& id &"</OrderId>"
soap=soap& "<CallBackUrl>"& backurl &"</CallBackUrl>"
soap=soap& "</requestData>"
soap=soap& "</SalePaymentRequest>"
soap=soap& "</soap:Body>"
soap=soap& "</soap:Envelope>"

dim xmlhttp 
set xmlhttp = server.Createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.Open "POST",posturl,false
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", SOAPAction

xmlhttp.send soap
Response.Write xmlhttp.responseText
Set xmlhttp = nothing
```